# Can I add permission to easyadmin list filters?

Tags: symfony5, easyadmin

I am doing awesome with EasyAdmin and Symfony 5. I love the way EasyAdmin normalize all the hard work. I can set permissions to menu and fields under forms, list or show. **I was wondering if there is a way to add permission to Filters.**

I have searched a lot in the [official documentation](https://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/EasyAdminBundle/index.html) (version 2.x) and off course also in google but can't find a way to set permission in filters using `easy_admin.yaml` file.

I am looking for something like the following:

```
easy_admin:
  entities:
    Task:
      list:
        filters: ['startTime', 'endTime', permission: ['ROLE_ADMIN']] // <===== like this one
```

I see these are not working either:

`filters: ['startTime', 'endTime', permission: ['ROLE_ADMIN']]` // <== array

or

`filters: {'startTime', 'endTime', permission: ['ROLE_ADMIN']}` // <== object

Would you please someone help me to know if there is a way to add permission for `Filters` in EasyAdmin?

Answer (score 1):

For set permission, you must set it to each fields of filters.

```
easy_admin:
  entities:
    Task:
      list:
        filters:
          - startTime
          - { property: endTime, permission: ['ROLE_ADMIN'] }
```